# Advantages and disadvantages of reading a current-sense amplifier with different gains on I2C

Tags: current, amplifier, analog, i2c

I am writing an I2C wrapper for the [MAX9611](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9611-MAX9612.pdf) chip. For the current-sense amplifier (CSA), according to the datasheet there are 3 selectable gains (1x, 4x and 8x):

[image: MAX9611 internal diagram]

When I read the 12bit ADC registers for all 3 gains, I get the same raw values. But to convert it to real current I have to multiply them with some constants which are different for each gain, e.g. for 1x it is *1.075* and for 4x/8x constants are *0.269* and *0.134*. I have found these constants on some sample codes and I have no idea how they are calculated but I have found this table in datasheet but I can't make sure why:

[image]

So my guess is, when I select the *gain=8x*, the resolution (or accuracy?) of my reading is much higher compared with *gain=1x* but what will I lose in doing so?

So my question is, what are the advantages and disadvantages for reading from lower or higher gains? Also, what should be the correct multipliers if I want to convert raw ADC to real current? (the ADC is 12bit) I power the chip from a 3.3V source.

Comment: Gain means range. More gain - less range (and probably more noise).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. Is that the only thing? what about noise and other stuff?

Comment: Amplifiers are amplifying the noise together with the signal. Also you might look over the datasheet to see if there is any effect of different gains to the SNR.

Comment: @Sean87 - "for all 3 gains, I get the same raw values". That result makes no sense, assuming you have a sensible in-range current flowing in the sense resistor. Perhaps you are not reading valid data at all. I suggest you change to reading the temperature registers (and heat/cool the chip to ensure the value changes as expected) to validate your I2C routines. Seeing your specific schematic and specific CSA register values for all 3 gains, might highlight something to members here (add them to your question). Also seeing your I2C traces might allow readers to see something incorrect or unusual.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for pointing that out. I get correct temp values. for the currents, at the moment the sense resistor is just connected to ground (at it shows 3 as the raw value out of 4095, I guess the 3 is the offset that I have to calibrate for). I will do some measurement with a known current to make sure!

Comment: @SamGibson you were right I wasn't configuring the control registers correctly.

Comment: @Sean87 - Thanks for the update. I didn't know that register programming was definitely an issue here, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer for that part of your question :-) If you haven't got one already, I2C analysers (some are quite cheap, or decoders are built into some 'scopes etc) can capture traces of what is happening "on the wire". That makes it much easier to detect when what we *think* our code is doing, is not *actually* what our code is doing. Been there, done that ;-) Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different gains allow you to sense a wider range of currents. The higher the current, then the higher the gain you will need (although that sounds backwards).

The current-sense resistor is limited by the heat it can dissipate, usually just a couple of watts. So to sense higher current, you need the sense voltage to be lower (a smaller value sense resistor, like .005 ohm) to keep the wattage in range. A common maximum sense voltage would be around 250 millivolts for sensing around 10 amps or less, and more like 50 millivolts if you're sensing up to 50 amps.

For best resolution, you want to amplify the sensed voltage to maximize the range of the ADC, without saturating the ADC. So you will select your gain for your desired maximum sense voltage. There is no advantage or disadvantage to a particular gain - there is simply one gain that will work best for your maximum sense voltage.

Your second question: What are those silly multipliers? You have a 12-bit ADC (4096 values) that convert a voltage range of only 440 millivolts. So the "Full-Scale Sense Voltage" is simply the .44 volt ADC input range divided by the gain. The "LSB Step Size" is simply the voltage necessary to change the output by one.